# How to read the maven documentation - list of xml-tags

Tags: xml, maven, properties, pom.xml, documentation

Maven offers guidelines (http://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html). These guidelines provide explainations and examples. But where do I find maven specific information which are not part of the maven guideline (documentation)?

Following example:
I want to use a local repository. I'm searching for it and there is this site:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#using-the-internal-repository. Where do I find further possible xml tags to specify the repository environment? I'm not able (searching wrong?!) to find more information in the maven doc. But there are more possible tags (e.g. enabled, checksumPolicy https://gist.github.com/berlinbrown/1213774)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the xsd here:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd

It defines all possible XML tags for the POM.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier Thanks!